# How to tap a push notification to open a specific screen in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, push-notification, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI.

I want to open a specific screen other than Root View by clicking the push notification.
There are several ways to open it using StoryBoard, but not without StoryBoard.

How can I achieve it without using StoryBoard?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        willPresent notification: UNNotification,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions)
        -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        // I want to open a screen other than Root View here.
        completionHandler()
    }
    ... }
```